# Active model serializer each_serializer vs serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have noticed when I want to fetch the collection of objects (@user.all) I have to user each_serializer

```
render json: @users, root: 'data', each_serializer: User::ShowSerializer
```

whereas when I have to have a single object show action serializer works.

```
render json: @user, root: 'data', serializer: User::ShowSerializer
```

Please can anyone explain the difference between the two

Comment: each_serializer is used when we have more then 1 record, serializer is used when we have single record

Answer (score 15):

Think of it as the `each` iterator in Ruby.

When you have a single record `@user`, no iteration is required, and in return you get a single serialized resource. Here we directly apply a `serializer`:

```
render json: @user, root: 'data', serializer: User::ShowSerializer
```

Think of this as the same as

```
User::ShowSerializer(@user)
```

When you have a collection of records, such as `@user.all`, you have to iterate over each resource to get a serialized collection of records. Here we apply `each_serializer`:

```
render json: @users, root: 'data', each_serializer: User::ShowSerializer
```

This is the same as

```
@users.each do |user|
  User::ShowSerializer(user)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

For a collection

**:serializer** specifies the collection serializer and

**:each_serializer** specifies the serializer for each resource in the collection.
For a single resource, the :serializer option is the resource serialize

Please  take a look at [this documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#how-options-are-parsed) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Basically 
**:serializer** returns a JSON Object

and **:each_serializer** returns array of JSON Objects